# Failed to load library liblwjgl.so

Tags: gradle, lwjgl

I was trying to export .jar file of my lwjgl game so I can send it to my friend using gradle. When I've opened jar in /build/libs via typing java -jar [name of file] this error message appear:

```
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
    a) Add the directory that contains the shared library to -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath.
    b) Add the JAR that contains the shared library to the classpath.
[LWJGL] Enable debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true for better diagnostics.
[LWJGL] Enable the SharedLibraryLoader debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.DebugLoader=true for better diagnostics.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: liblwjgl.so
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:164)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:63)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:51)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:100)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer$Default.<clinit>(Pointer.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Callback.<clinit>(Callback.java:40)
    at org.example.app.Engine.init(Engine.kt:64)
    at org.example.app.Engine.run(Engine.kt:53)
    at org.example.app.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:4)
    at org.example.app.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt)
```

I know that this kinda says what I need to do, but I don't really understand where should I add for example "-Djava.library.path".

here's my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.30'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

project.ext.lwjglVersion = "3.3.0"
project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-linux"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:$lwjglVersion")

    implementation 'org.joml:joml:1.10.3'
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-assimp"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-assimp::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb::$lwjglNatives"
}

jar {
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.example.app.ApplicationKt'
    } from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/../lib'
        }
    }
}
```

gradle.properties:

```
kotlin.code.style=official
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=--illegal-access=permit
```

It works perfectly fine in IntelliJ, it gives an error only when trying to open outside of the IDE.

If it matters I'm using linux (POP_OS) and I'm writing this game in kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently not including the runtime natives jar files of LWJGL into your fat jar file.

So, you don't need to add any JVM arguments like `-Djava.library.path` or `-Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath` but merely must make sure that the "natives-linux" dependencies/jar files are in the classpath when you run the jar.

One way to achieve this in your case is by not only iterating over the compile-time dependencies but over the runtime dependencies in your jar task to also collect those and add them to the fat jar file that you build, because you definitely *will* need them at runtime.

So, change this line:

```
} from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
```

to:

```
} from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
```

LWJGL 3 itself will then, at runtime, scan the classpath and detect the shared libraries files in the jar files, extract and load them appropriately.